# How to put facebook comments system in featherlight ajax loaded page?

Tags: php, ajax, lightbox, facebook-comments, featherlight.js

I'm using featherlight plugin to make a gallery in my site. For each gallery element I click it loads a page which content (title, tags, imgs etc) comes from database and it's changed according to id sent by GET method. I would like to insert a facebook comments box for each gallery item, and it works when I open the its page in other window, but doesn't works when open using the featherlight plugin to the page as lightbox.

**This code calls the featherlight plugin:**

```
<?php
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM jobs") as $job) {
        echo "
        <div class='".$job['catJob']."' style='background:url(".$job['thumbJob']."); '>
        <a href='#' onclick='bodyNoScroll()' data-featherlight='jobs.php?j=".$job['idJob']."'>
        </div>";
    }
?>
```

**And this is the page I load with the plugin**

```
<?php
if(count($_GET)){
    require_once("conection.php");
    $jobId = $_GET['j'];
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE idJob=$jobId") as $job){
        $nameJob = $job['nameJob'];  
        $descJob = $job['descJob'];
        $imgJob = $job['imgJob'];
        $catJob = $job['catJob'];
        $videoJob = $job['videoJob'];
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
    window.onload(function(){
    removertodos = document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML.replace("todos ", "");
    document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML = removertodos;
}); 
</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jobstyle.css">


</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="containerjob">
<?php echo  "
    <div id='description'>
        <h2>$nameJob</h2>
        <p id='tags'>$catJob</p>
        <p id='descjob'>$descJob</p>
    </div>";
    if ($imgJob!="")
        echo "<img src='$imgJob' alt=''>";
    if ($videoJob!="")
        echo $videoJob;
    echo "
    <div class='fb-comments' data-href='jobs.php?j=".$jobId."' data-width='100%' data-numposts='5'></div>
    <div id='outros'></div>"
?>  
</div>
```

Any idea what can I do?